# Android certificate transparency

Tags: android, certificate-transparency

I am trying to use the sdk from babylon to test CT in android app.
I tried as given here https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-android

but I am getting the logs System.out: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.org -> Success: SCT not enabled for insecure connection

I am very sure these are secure connections and I have valid SCT for those.
When I digged in to the code, I can see that `

```
val host = chain.request().url().host()
        val certs = chain.connection()?.handshake()?.peerCertificates()?.map { it as X509Certificate } ?: emptyList()

        val result = if (chain.connection()?.socket() is SSLSocket) {
            verifyCertificateTransparency(host, certs)
        } else {
            VerificationResult.Success.InsecureConnection(host)
        }`
```

its coming to the else part and thus giving the error. I am see that the connection is having null value. Any idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full URL being used it is quite hard to know what issue you were having. The code "should" only reach the `else` when it is an insecure connection (i.e. http instead of https).

The library does have a logging mechanism in place that may help debugging issues. When creating the okhttp interceptor, set `logger = BasicAndroidCRLogger(BuildConfig.DEBUG)`.